Can I write an HTML for iFrame that recognizes if its parent uses dark mode?
I work for an online university that uses a proprietary Learning Management System developed by our larger parent company. We want to be able to create embeddable HTML blocks to add a bit of style to our lessons. Our LMS recently updated to allow users to select "dark mode" in their user preferences. (The LMS doesn't recognize whether the browser is in dark mode or not). We want our embedded iframes to be able to swap between dark and light when users change how the LMS looks. Unfortunately, we don't have access to the LMS HTML code, so we can't ask the parent code to trigger changes within an iframe.
We've been able to work around this by making a toggle switch for each embed so users can update the way embeds looks manually, but that's obviously a pretty clunky process for the user. It would be best if one of our embeds could sample the color of its parent page to gauge whether or not the parent is using dark mode.
Right now, we've got an html checkbox that we use to let the user manually switch to dark mode.
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
      <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
          <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>
    <em>Enable Dark Mode</em><br>
  </div>

That checkbox speaks to a javascript page that actually executes the switchTheme() function to make the switch.
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    }
    else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
    }    
}

toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);


Everything works as designed, but it would be better to be able to be able to set the theme to 'dark' just by recognizing if the parent page is dark.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

the only way to exchange information between an iFrame and its parent is to use the postMessage() method

if they're in the same domain you can use window.parent.contentDocument to access the containing frame, and then check its attributes.

The window.frames array
You can iterate through the frames array of the main window and set light/dark mode on each iframe element as well as the main window.
This approach will  fail if frames' content is from a different origin.
The following code is a proof of concept: it is missing the bit that when adding a new, or changing the content of an existing iframe element, code would need to call switchTheme in context of the main window. If doing this within an iframe element, try making the call as top.switchTheme() first.
Note This code does not run as a code snippet due to the manner SO snippets are sanitized. It ran, as designed and without security errors, when tested in both Firefox and Edge.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Iframe themes</title>

<style>
:root[data-theme="light"] {
   color: black;
   background-color: ivory;
}
:root[data-theme="dark"] {
   color: green;
   background-color: black;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
     <label class="theme-switch" for="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
          <div class="slider round"></div>
     </label>
     <em>Enable Dark Mode</em><br>
  </div>

  <hr>
  Main window
  <hr>

<iframe srcdoc="Iframe content"></iframe>

<script>
"use strict";
const toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');

function switchTheme() {
    const theme = toggleSwitch.checked ? 'dark' : 'light'; 
    const windows = Array.from(window.frames);

    windows.push(window);
    windows.forEach(win => {
        win.document.documentElement.dataset.theme = theme;
    });
}

switchTheme() // initialise
toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>

